# ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. Unity

Tags: c#, события, unity3d-editor, делегаты, unity3d-faq

Есть два класса `SubjectSelection` и `AddScoreUI`. Так же есть объект (конфеты) который спавнится на карте. И когда игрок подбирает его я вызываю ивент, что бы обновить счетчик собранных конфет. В методе OnEnable я пытаюсь подписаться на метод, но мне выдает ошибку `ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.`

```
public class SubjectSelection : MonoBehaviour
{

    public AddScoreUI _scoreUI;

    public delegate void ScoreHandlerDelegate();
    public event ScoreHandlerDelegate OnScoreHandlerEvent;

    private void Awake()
    {
        OnScoreHandlerEvent += _scoreUI.AddScore;
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"))
        {
            OnScoreHandlerEvent?.Invoke();
            OnScoreHandlerEvent -= _scoreUI.AddScore;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class AddScoreUI : MonoBehaviour
{

    private int _candyCount;

    [SerializeField] private TMP_Text _candeText;

    public int CandyCount
    {
        get
        {
            return _candyCount;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_candyCount >= 0)
            {
                _candyCount = value;
            }
            else
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

    }

    private void OnValidate()
    {
        
    }

    public void AddScore() 
    {
        _candyCount++;
        _candeText.text = _candyCount.ToString(_candyCount + "/50");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильное использование `_candyCount.ToString(_candyCount + "/50")`

правильно будет вот так

```
_candeText.text = _candyCount + "/50";
```

или так

```
_candeText.text = $"{_candyCount}/50";
```